# Calculate probability of a corrective move to the average over a finite period

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, average

I'm not a mathematician; I do have some reasonable math knowledge, but have always had struggles with probability. So while I am looking for the calculation to my problem, I would also desire some explanation. **I've edited this question from an earlier version** that seemed to be getting off track on my price movement illustration (as all the comments by lulu show), rather than focusing on what I'm really trying to understand and solve with respect to probability. **I hope what I have now is clear and more focused mathematically.**

*Assume* the following: An integer value between 20 and 200 is generated each day for 10 days. There is a level of randomness to this, but two things affect the randomness:

1. No day will be exactly equal to the day before, some variation will occur.
2. Over any 10 days, *at least by day 10*, 100 **will** be what the *average* of the set calculates to; this means that if a large number of greater than 100 values are generated early in the period, there are increasing odds of the latter days being less than 100 (perhaps significantly less, and vice versa). Of course, there could be just small pushes to each side of 100 level, as each day corrects the day before, in which case the probability remains fairly "normal" and "equal" on which direction from 100 the next day's number would be.

At some point, since the assumption is that it *will* return to an 100 average at least by day 10, given *how far it has moved away from average* and *how many days are left in the set*, there is the possibility of yielding an increasing probability that a day (or series of days) will end up opposite the earlier move to counter balance it to reach the 100 goal by the end of the set 10 days.

I'm seeking a formula to calculate *the probability that the next day* in the sequence *begins* and/or *completes* a corrective move back to the 100 average, given the varying history of what might have transpired before and what is capable of happening in the time remaining. So the first day would be completely random, but the 2nd and following days would begin to shift probabilities of a correction (or expansion/contraction if day 1 = 100 value or any set of days prior already averaged to 100) based on the finite time remaining, amount needing to be corrected to get to 100, and allowable values in the range to get to that correction.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  First of all, you speak of the daily range of "price movements" as being $100$...but "price movements" would suggest change in price, not price itself.  Is that what you meant?  And as you want to work with percents, a change of $100$ would mean doubling or going to $0$?  More to the point:  to use data to predict future moves is tricky.  What model are you assuming for the price action going forward?

Comment: @lulu There is a daily change in price (high - low), and that range is what this is about. I'm assuming 100 to make it "easy" and because ultimately a percentage is what I would get to, but 200 "points" would be double the average of 100 "points" (so 200% of the daily range of 100 points = 200 points, where points is the measure of the price range). As to your last question, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "model", but price going forward here is to assume there is an increasing probability of a change (contraction / # of days) such that there is a return to average range overall.

Comment: I still don't get what you are saying about price changes, but lets just say you have a time series (which either tracks the price at various time steps or records the price change over the relevant interval).  Now, what does it mean to say you want to assume an "increasing probability" of some sort of change?  What functional form do you want for that probability?  Really:  modeling future behavior is complicated.  You need to be precise about what you are assuming.

Comment: People have, of course, studied models of price action that allow mean reversion.  The usual process one uses is [Ornstein Uhlenbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) but, as you'll see, it's fairly complicated.

Comment: @lulu I have assumed a time series; I noted a "daily" range. I also noted the average was of the last 10 days. So from any particular point, if we assume an eventual correction, then as time goes on without a correction, I assume probability would increase for a correction. So if we had 5 days of over 100, then by that point I would think (?) we are nearing a 100% probability that day 6 would start to correct, followed by 4 more days of possible correction (since by the end the next 5 days after the 5 days of expansion, the average should be back to 100 in the example).

Comment: Really, this depends on your model.  Once can imagine a process in which, each day, independently of all other days, there was a probability $p$ of reverting to the mean (however defined).  That process would have no "memory" so the fact that you'd gone ages without reversion wouldn't have any impact on the next day's move.  You could also imagine a process in which that probability $p$ was a function of how far you were from the mean.

Comment: Should say:  It is (extremely) difficult to conceive of any process in which you were " near $100\%$" likely to mean revert soon...if people believed that then the price would have already gone back to the mean.  If I know a stock is extremely likely to move in a particular way tomorrow I'll buy it or sell it short to profit from that move, as will a lot of other people.

Comment: @lulu I'm not talking about movement to a mean "price" (value) but rather the  "range" of price change (volatility). Price movements go from periods of expansion to contraction quite regularly (especially in the Forex market, which is my actual market of interest). So my process would be more as described, where *p* is a function of how many days and how far it has traveled from mean, with an expectation of a return to mean over the next *x* number of days (trading slows down and price settles down in volatility).

Comment: Well, as I've said, I really can't sort out what you are asking and at this point I doubt I am helping, so I'll stop commenting.  My last observation is that there is an enormous body of literature on the modeling of market prices.  I suggest taking a look at standard models to see if anythings done pairs up with what you are looking for.  Good luck.

Comment: @lulu I've reduced the problem down in a clarification to the math I'm looking for, trying to separate it from the "price" idea (since that seems to be getting in the way of understanding what I'm seeking).